Join Stack Overflow’s CEO and me for the first Stack IRL Community Event in NYC on October 10th, 2024 (postponed)
Update - October 3, 2024: This event is now postponed.

Update - September 25, 2024: You have until October 1st to sign up

We've begun to send invites out to people who have expressed interest in attending. If you signed up please check your inbox for either an invitation or a request for confirmation info that was missing when you submitted the google form. We still have the potential to book a slightly larger room if a few more people are able to attend so we're leaving the form open until Tuesday, October 1st. We hope to see you there.

One of the great staples - and most fun parts - of online communities is, ironically, the chance to meet offline.  It’s something that I’ve enjoyed greatly throughout my career. Since joining Stack Overflow, I’ve wanted to do them here as well. It’s a valuable opportunity for staff to meet with the folks who really make the sites work and to get the chance to hear directly from you.  So I’m delighted to announce that our first “Stack IRL” in-person community event will take place on Thursday, October 10th, from 6-9 PM ET in NYC!
If you are in the New York area, I hope that you will join Stack Overflow’s CEO Prashanth Chandrasekar, myself, Adam Lear, Rosie, and Sasha for the evening at a venue in Midtown. We’ll have beverages and food, and this will be an opportunity to mingle with us and one another. There is no formal ‘program’ outside of a brief welcome and the chance to chat with each other.
Space is extremely limited, so if you are interested in attending, please sign up ASAP. We understand you may want to bring a guest, so there is an option on the form to let us know if you plan to bring a “plus-one” (Because space is limited, we can only accommodate one guest per person). We’ll keep RSVPs open for two weeks, and we’ll send you the location (or let you know if you are on the wait-list) once we close them.
We hope that this will be the first of many in-person meetups in the future. If it goes well, we will look into doing more of these in other major cities. I really hope that if you are in the NYC area, you’ll join us. I’d love the opportunity to thank you in person for everything that you do to make the site (and the whole network) a success and a vital part of the Internet’s infrastructure.

mumble mumble... IRL... grumble mumble

Lol. Maybe next time @JNat

@JNat suppose it was being held where you're located, would join in such a case?

I suspect the grumbling is more the implication that this waves hands at the pervasive Internet is somehow still not really part of Life, @shadow

What Shog said, yes xD

@DanMašek • Limited number of spaces; • Only one guest; • A datetime with 10 in it; • “beverages and food”… I'm pretty sure Prashanth intends to eliminate attendees one-by-one (as an ironic consequence of their vices, of course, and not at all deliberately) until only one remains, at which point he will offer them the position of CEO during a remarkable demonstration of Stack's space programme. (How does it work? Why, unicorn power!)

Haha @wizzwizz4 - you've cracked the code! Jokes aside, I'm really looking forward to seeing as many of you as possible IRL and having a great conversation.

Why not just tell us how many spaces there are instead of that cryptic "limited space"?

@Lambie - Its to save face in the aftermath, there might be 50 spaces but when only 8 people with their +1 turn up, the photos won't be as embarrassing

@ShadowWizard an email was sent postponing the event with an emphasis that it is not cancelled but without any future dates set.

@PrashanthChandrasekar hi there. You can also have virtual conversation with us in chat, we don't bite. Well, most of us, at least. There was once upon a time "Town Hall" event in chat, where a new feature was introduced to make it easier to arrange, the ability to place a chat in timeout, so that the official speaker can write without others interfering. I hope this can be brought back again, and used to bridge the currently very wide gap between the company and the community. Thanks.

Hey folks. I've received confirmation from staff that the edit is correct, the event is postponed. I cannot elaborate further about this, just figured I'd confirm.

Can someone say anything else about why the event has been postponed?

@ТymaGaidash I guess it just wasn't convenient. Keep in mind that the person looking for "having a great conversation" hasn't engaged us here for years -- in fact other than that earlier comment here, the last one is from Nov 19, 2020 at 17:01.

@ТymaGaidash when they say "we are transparent" just think of cases like this, that's all.

For clarity, will those attending the event earn Not a Robot badges on Stack Overflow?

Happy to say that yes, we're taking the "Not a robot" stickers with us and we will be assigning  the badges to those in attendance who appropriately complete the necessary steps as laid out on the stickers (basically, you go to a particular site and enter your ID number from the sticker while logged in.)

What if we are robots?

Be in disguise?

@Philippe I didn't know there is also a sticker. Is there a picture/screenshot of it somewhere?

@EndAntisemiticHate if you are a robot then you will be assimilated.

I can't take part as I'm bit too far, however I'll ask some questions for the benefit of others.

Are there any requirements related to the SE profile of the one who send the request?
If not, how would you choose? Is there e.g. consideration for mods?
What is the "Code of Conduct" for those who arrive and will meet the CEO? (e.g. how to approach him, what can and can't be asked, etc.)

Enough for now, let others ask the rest, if interested.

Responding in order:

Requirements:  none, other than that you be willing to attend if invited, or to let us know that you won't so thaat we can pass along the spot.
We're going for a representative mix of folks.  We're not going to bias toward all mods or all non-mods, but you're goingt o need to have SOME involvement to be considered.  One or two comments likely won't do it.  Beyond that, I believe the intent is to bias toward early responses.
There are no rules for that, beyond the bounds of courtesy.  We believe that folks here are generally respectful and he has indicated  (cont)


(cont.) no questions are out of bounds.  Obviously, we're trying to talk to as many of the folks there as possible, so please allow others to ask questions, after you've had a chance.

"No questions are out of bounds" - a bit too far to travel for me sadly, but I'm curious to see if we also get (substantial) answers (especially since the relationship between community and management/staff has been rather strained in the past years) Some clearing of the air would be good, but my hopes are honestly limited (feel free to pleasantly surprise me however)

status-completed
The options format in the last question is weird.

You should be using a radio button instead of checkbox.


thanks for catching that! I switched that question to multiple choice, so only one option can be selected

On October 3rd an email was sent by a Stack Overflow staff member (on behalf of Philippe) indicating that the event is postponed (the same email address that shared the invitation originally). I have included a screenshot of the email but redacted information that SO may not want to share publicly (email addresses, locations, etc.).

Transcript:

We'd like to share this important message from Philippe, the VP of Community:
I am writing today to inform you that we have made the decision to reschedule our Stack IRL event for New York City. A new date has not yet been set. The decision to do this was driven by a number of factors, including a feeling that the timing was just not right for many of our attendees (including those that wished they could attend but had conflicts). However, we want to be very clear that this is a reschedule, and not a cancellation. It's important to me, and to Prashanth, that we make the time to meet with community members in person and we are committed to doing that.
In the meantime, if there were particular issues that you wanted to discuss with us, I want to make some time available [redacted].
I'm terribly sorry that we will not be able to meet you this month. I was very much looking forward to this. However, we will keep your information and we will inform you when we reschedule this event.
Best regards, 
Philippe


@ShadowWizard It did get removed from the events page though

We don’t know where the event will be in NYC?

@ТymaGaidash not relevant, there's no event. And the location is kept secret on purpose, as they don't want people who were not invited to barge in.

@ТymaGaidash it will not be. It's postponed. Presumably, when it's re-scheduled, it might be on a different place than it was initially planned.

If they reschedule it to their private yacht, I'd consider joining if they come pick us up with it. It's always nice taking a swim from a boat. Unfortunately, I'd probably have to talk to somebody, too.

Just for what it's worth, this is not actually the first.
Back when SO was (fairly) new, they had a few in-person events. I went to one at the office in Denver (which I'm not sure exists any more, but did at the time).

Pretty sure Denver still exis- oh, the office. Ah, good times... I learned the existence of "bourbon bacon apple tarts" at one of those, and still occasionally make them for myself.

Hey @Shog9--in fact, I spent most of my time at that event talking to you...

Well while I'm the last to take the side of the current management, I'd say it can be considered the first such event under the current management. :) (Assuming your intent is to defy the usage of the word "first" and Jeremy edit being rolled back)

I'd suggest streaming the meeting on Twitch and YouTube if you want the event to have reach. That's what everyone else seems to be doing these days.

Depends if this is just a meet and greet, or whether Prashanth/Phillipe will be giving a speech or anything. Watching randos mingle isn't that useful :)

@Robotnik you mustn't have been watching what the regular Twitch content is. No speeches needed, just meeting and mingling is enough to make for great entertainment. If someone wants to make a speech that's a plus but IRL itself is the main event.

I dunno. I'd liken it to streaming PAX or Comicon. Watching people mingle at a distance from a camera on a stand? Boring. Streaming panels, presentations, or keynote speakers though? That's something worth watching.

@Robotnik off course not, have someone from staff or attending walk around taking the audience/chat along for the mingle. I pledge to spam emotes in chat.

"regular Twitch content"... Well, to clarify, 'Just Chatting' is a relatively new directory, and kinda cringe. But, yeah, that's most of Twitch nowadays.

@bad_coder - That I could get behind :)

It being streamed/recorded would also mean folks (not only staff, but also attendees) would need to be more guarded/careful. Unless there's anything actually worth streaming, it would probably not be worth the cost/effort.

@V2Blast You need to be guarded when walking down the street if you don't want to be filmed. (Isn't it a US legal saying: no privacy is to be expected in public places?!) But ok, if they want an event for a handful of people in NYC and leave everyone else out that's fine by me. I'm sure Philippe would have some great party lines and good talking points, I was looking forward to hearing him in an informal setting.

I appreciate your confidence in my party lines. I’m already warehousing appropriate dad jokes for this event. However, the main purpose of this event is for us to connect with folks in person and I think a random camera following is going to change that dynamic.  We have other plans for other types of things to communicate in other ways. And yes, YouTube streams are one that I would love to trial at least once, for content that’s well suited to that medium. Probably best not to waste that on my dad jokes.

@Philippe but selfies won't hurt, and will give those interested something to show to their grandchildren, when the day will come.

Dad jokes? I'm too old for dad jokes.

@Philippe: Now I demand a YouTube stream of nothing but your dad jokes... :P


We’ll keep RSVPs open for two weeks, and we’ll send you the location (or let you know if you are on the wait-list) once we close them

How large do you expect this event to be? How will the attendees get selected? Is it on a first-come-first basis or will there be a some sort of lottery? If I add a plus-one, would I get lower priority if a lottery is implemented?

Partial answers to your questions are in this comment by Phillippe. No indication of whether those bringing plus-ones would get lower priority.

Adding a plus one will not give you lower priority in being added to the list of attendees. We want everyone to be comfortable and we know that bringing along a friend, partner, or coworker can help with that. However, for people who end up being invited from the waitlist, we may not have space to include their plus ones. We will send more information via email to folks who sign up.
